# can google perf tools be used for profiling C applications?

Tags: c++, c, profiler

The "C++" figures prominently everywhere, so I was wondering if I can also profile C applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Yes.  Definitely.  Without a doubt.

Comment: Wow, that's enthusiasm. Thanks.

Comment: Answers have a minimum character count, so I figured I'd be very clear!